# Simplifiying (or getting the exponent thing outside) the expression $\{({\rm complicated\, stuff})^{1/n}\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractional-part

So i have like a very complicated expression involving many variables, and i want to simplify it, the only problem comes from the fact that this complicated expression is itself inside a fractional part $\{...\}$ which we define to be $$\{x\}={\rm fractional\,part\,of\,}x=x-{\rm IntegerPart}(x)$$
in particular this complicated expression takes the form $$\{({\rm complicated\, stuff})^{1/n}\}=({\rm complicated\, stuff})^{1/n}-{\rm IntegerPart}(({\rm complicated\, stuff})^{1/n})$$ I tried raising to the $n$ power and using newton's binomial theorem but we don't have things that get simplified

if anyone knows a way to write that in an alternative way (like getting rid of the sqrt) that would help very much!

> **TLDR;** How to simplify $\{({\rm complicated\, stuff})^{1/n}\}$, or how to write $\{({\rm complicated\, stuff})^{1/n}\}=f({\rm complicated\, stuff})^{1/n}$

if anything is unclear feel free to ask!

---

the exact expression is $$\left\{\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^{1/n}}\right\}$$ p,q, integers

Comment: there is not a general way to do this. You should post your exact expression

Comment: Is this from a textbook/competition? If so, then perhaps you are not expected to write the 'complicated stuff' in fractional and integer parts, do manipulations, etc. but are supposed to cleverly show that the fractional part is always zero, or has a fixed form...

Comment: @StellaBiderman $$\left\{\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^{1/n}}\right\}$$ p,q, integers

Comment: @shardulc no it's just me wondering      (not from a textbook or a contest)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that
$0 < p < q$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^{1/n}}
&=\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{q-p}{q}\right)^{1/n}}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{q}{q-p}\right)^{1/n}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{q-p+p}{q-p}\right)^{1/n}\\
&=\left(1+\dfrac{p}{q-p}\right)^{1/n}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$(1+x)^n
\ge 1+nx
$,
$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n
\ge 1+x
$
so that
$(1+x)^{1/n}
\le
1+\frac{x}{n}
$.

Therefore
$\left(1+\dfrac{p}{q-p}\right)^{1/n}
\le 1+\dfrac{p}{n(q-p)}
$
or
$\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^{1/n}}
\le 1+\dfrac{p}{n(q-p)}
= 1+\dfrac{p/q}{n(1-p/q)}
= 1+\dfrac{1}{n(q/p-1)}
$.

Does this help?

(added in response to a comment)

If
$\dfrac{1}{n(q/p-1)} < 1$,
then
$\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^{1/n}} \right\rfloor
= 1$.

This happens if
$n
> \dfrac{1}{(q/p-1)}
= \dfrac{p}{q-p}
$.

Also,
by the generalized binomial theorem
if $n$ is large,
if $r = p/q$,
then
$(1-r)^{-1/n}
=1+\frac{r}{n}+\frac{r^2(1+n)}{2n^2}+...
$.
This doesn't behave well,
since the coefficient
of $r^m$
is about
$\frac{1}{m!n}
$.

It might be better to look at
$(1+s)^{1/n}
$
where
$s = \frac{p}{q-p}$.
This is
$(1+s)^{1/n}
=1+\frac{s}{n}-\frac{s^2(n-1)}{2n^2}+...
$.
Since this is an enveloping series,
$1+\frac{s}{n}-\frac{s^2(n-1)}{2n^2}
< (1+s)^{1/n}
< 1+\frac{s}{n}
$.

Comment: but how can we deduce the fractional part then? i know that $$\left\{            1+\dfrac{1}{n(q/p-1)}            \right\}=\left\{            \dfrac{1}{n(q/p-1)}            \right\}$$ but how is that gonna help us deduce $$\left\{\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{p}{q}\right)^{1/n}}\right\}$$ thanks for your answer through

Comment: For large enough n, the value is between 1 and 2, so the fractional part is the expression minus one.

Comment: Then you just have to compute.

Comment: i started working again on the problem, your inequality only gives one bound, I'm trying as much as possible to find a specific value when $n$ is very large